# queryFn must be return promise using react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I use react-query.
The result value should be determined according to the query key.
However, when it is a specific query key, api calls should not be made.

Is there any problem with the code below?
I'm worried about breaking the react-query rules.
please help me.

```
function useTest(a,b) {
  const {
    fetchNextPage,
    data,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(['test', a, b], ({ pageParam = 1 }) => {
    
    if (b=== 3) { return; }

    return fetchTest(pageParam, a)
  }, {
    cacheTime: 0,
    staleTime: Infinity,

  });

}
```

Comment: I guess the `return;` could be `return Promise.resolve()` if the callback must return a Promise - does your code currently produce errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think react-query will wrap the result in a Promise anyways, so you can do:

```
useQuery(key, () => "foo")
```

as well. In your example, just be aware that `data` can then be `undefined`. It might be better to *disable* the query in this case:

```
useInfiniteQuery(['test', a, b], fetchTest, { enabled: b !== 3 })
```

Comment: very very thank you. I do not speak English well. i don't know enabled option. :)